# Calling ampscript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

The problem is the connection between the template ampscipt names and the set names in the library. 
It’s not connecting and pulling the copy

```
%%[

Set @m1 = 'DIN'
Set @p1_copy = TreatAsContent(Concat("%%=v(",@m1,"_copy)=%%"))
Set @DIN_copy ="workie workie"

]%%


<p>

load copy here %%=v(@p1_copy)=%% like this text.
</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure I understand your use-case completely, but you certainly can do what you've illustrated in your code but you have to separate the double-percents in the [**concat**](https://ampscript.guide/concat).

You'll also need to define `@DIN_copy` before you use the TreatAsContent/Concat combo.  The [**TreatAsContent**](https://ampscript.guide/treatascontent) forces the AMPscript to get evaluated.

```html
%%[

Set @m1 = 'DIN'
Set @DIN_copy = "workie workie"
Set @p1_copy = TreatAsContent(Concat("%", "%=v(",@m1,"_copy)=%","%"))

]%%
<p>
load copy here %%=v(@p1_copy)=%% like this text.
</p>
```

(Credit: [**This answer**](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/226506/5202) by [**jake314159**](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/26886/jake314159))

Lastly, template and email code are evaluated from the top down, so there should be no need to do anything special to define/read variable values between template and email.  It's all the same context at the time the AMPscript is evaluated.